# JavaScript Aysnchronous Call in For Loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, asynchronous

i want to check about 3000 items in a List in a loop. in each step i have to make an asynchronous httprequest on a page. making this a a recursive function ist throwing `InternalError: too much recursion`
This is my code so far:

```
var iteratorObject = new function(){
    this.currentStep = -1;
    this.iterationList = {};

    this.start = function(list){
         this.iterationList = list;
         this.next(0);
    }

    this.next = function(value) {
        this.currentStep = value;
        if(this.currentStep +1 == this.iterationList.length){
            return
        }
        var currentID = this.iterationList[this.currentStep];

        //Do Aysnc HttpRequest on succeed call this.next(value +1);
    }

}

var iterator = iteratorObject;
var iterationList = Object.keys([Object]);
    iterator.start(iterationList);
```

How do i change my code to avoid recursive functions and only process one request at a time?

Comment: You can't do this in a `for` loop unless you want to write a framework to do _promises_. You look like you're pretty close though - just rewrite `next` so it looks at `currentStep` instead of needing a `value`.

Comment: Calling next in a callback would still be a recursive function? I there a way to get an event listner on currentStep calling the next() function?

Sorry, i'm a bit unexperienced in JS

Comment: You might look at this jsbin I prepared: http://jsbin.com/kacabu/1/edit?js,console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to add another solution, I thought this was an interesting problem, so here's something I cooked up based on your original solution:

```
function Iterator(doWork) {
    var done, start;

    done = function () {
        start();
    };

    start = function () {
        doWork(done);
    };

    // Export this method.
    this.start = start;
}
```

And usage is:

```
<ul id="times">
    Iterations...
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var maxIterations = 7000,
        $times = $('#times');

    var iterator = new Iterator(function (next) {
        var now = new Date();

        window.setTimeout(function () {
            var ms = (new Date() - now);

            $times.append($('<li></li>').text('Iteration ' + ($times.find('li').length + 1) + ': ' + ms + ' ms'));

            maxIterations -= 1;
            if (maxIterations > 0) {
                next();
            }
        }, 100);
    });

    iterator.start();
});
</script>
```

Which led to an interesting observation: Chrome has a way better timer than Internet Explorer.

Chrome sample output:

```
Iteration 5687: 101 ms
Iteration 5688: 101 ms
Iteration 5689: 101 ms
Iteration 5690: 101 ms
Iteration 5691: 101 ms
Iteration 5692: 101 ms
Iteration 5693: 101 ms
Iteration 5694: 101 ms
Iteration 5695: 100 ms
Iteration 5696: 101 ms
Iteration 5697: 101 ms
Iteration 5698: 101 ms
Iteration 5699: 102 ms
```

And now for Internet Explorer:

```
•Iteration 5687: 92 ms
•Iteration 5688: 93 ms
•Iteration 5689: 108 ms
•Iteration 5690: 93 ms
•Iteration 5691: 109 ms
•Iteration 5692: 92 ms
•Iteration 5693: 93 ms
•Iteration 5694: 109 ms
•Iteration 5695: 93 ms
•Iteration 5696: 92 ms
•Iteration 5697: 109 ms
•Iteration 5698: 93 ms
•Iteration 5699: 108 ms
```

Comment: Wow this looks really like the perfect solution for my problem. Thanks

Comment: @southzrgw Hey no problem.  Glad it's useful.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this type of problems when I wanted to copy records from external database to sql lite db using javascript.
generally for loops wont let you make recursive code that waits for ajax request call to go to the next iteration, then what I recommend you is :

1. make your code as global as possible to treat all objects the same way
2. get the objects put them into a table
3. make a function that takes the table of objects as parameter and each time
   it
   finishes the request it will call it self again with the next element till reaches the end of table.

example :

```
function recursive_calls(var elements[],var currentPosition){
    if(currentPosition<elements.length){
        $.ajax({
            url:some_api/elements[i].id,
            method:'get',
            success:function(res){
            //after some time ajax success function is fired
            //do some stuff here
            //call recursive_calls function again
                currentPosition++;
                recursive_calls(elements,currentPosition);
            }
        });
    }
}
```